# India : Income Tax not submitted by my ex employer

Tags: income-tax, india

My former employer has been consistent in deducting my Income Tax, however the same hasn't been paid for the financial year 2014-2015. I have also not been paid my complete full and final settlement in spite of repeated calls and mails there has been no response, now the company has been bought out and I am not sure what I need to do.

Could anyone advise me of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> My ex employer has been consistent in deducting my Income Tax, however the same hasn't been paid for the financial year 2014-2015

If tax as been deducted, your employer is obliged to credit the same to Income Tax. You can verify this by looking at form 26AS from [Income Tax website](http://contents.tdscpc.gov.in/).

You can write to the new company and request for the details. If not successful, hire a CA as it is a crime not to deposit the tax deducted.